# Examples of GraphRepository keywords

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Is there a location or resource of triggers for method names of a GraphRepository? I know you can do `XYZById` Or `XYZByNameAndId`, but is there any resource for what these are capable of? I would like to do something like `XYZByIdBetween(int start, int end)` but this does not work for Spring-data 2.1.0-RELEASE currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the following [URL](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.query-methods.details) in the official spring data documentation the explains how you can format your method names.